# magento2 jquery element.click is not working

Tags: magento2, ajax, wishlist

I have used anchor tag with some id, and want to perform ajax call on its call by using id.click() but its not working.here is my code in file view.phtml

```
<a id="pdp-add-to-wishlist"
   class="action pdp-towishlist"
   href="#">
    <span>
        <img class="favourite" src="image source" />
    </span>
</a>
```

and jquery is

```
<script>
require(['jquery'],function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#pdp-add-to-wishlist").click(function(){
            alert("hello");
        })
    });
});
```

if using with id its not working, but when used with class it works, but i need to work with id only.

I tried using with onclick() also but stuck in code

```
<a id="pdp-add-to-wishlist"
   class="action pdp-towishlist"
   href="#"
   onclick="addtowishlist()">
    <span>
        <img class="favourite" src="image source />
    </span>
</a>
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addtowishlist() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('wishlist/index/add'); ?>",
        data : {product:<?php echo $productId ?>},
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("succc");
        }
        error: function (e) {
            alert("not added");
        }
    });
}
```

but this has some bug which let the page to load for infinite time.

Comment: Check for DUPLICATE ids. Do view-source (ctrl+U), and search for `pdp-add-to-wishlist`

Comment: Change your id with class

Comment: I have checked with duplicate id, there is no duplicate id for this. i need to change class when id is clicked so i cannot use class

Comment: I tried with other ideas also but again its not working.. any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what are you doing
Try code example below may help. You should avoid use js in template if possible. Try to call it from single file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
 require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert'
], function($, alert) {
   $('#id-of-element').on('click', function(event){
        alert({
           content: $(event.target).parent().val()
        })
      })
   }
 );
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution which is working, used reference site as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639658/jquery-add-class-to-elements-child

```
<span class="pdp_product_to_wishlist">
    <a id="a_product_pdp_wish_id"
       href="#">
    <span>
        <img class="favourite" src="image source" />
    </span>
    </a>
</span>
```

in js i have written

```
$(".pdp_product_to_wishlist").find('#a_product_pdp_wish_id').removeClass('favourite active');
$(".pdp_product_to_wishlist").find('#a_product_pdp_wish_id').addClass('favourite active');
```

which has resolved my problem, I just tried other options.